# Запрет на создание процессов, работы с файловой системой и интернетом

Tags: c#, процесс, автоматизация

Доброго времени суток! При написании подсистемы тестирования пользовательских решений задач по программированию столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Необходимо запретить отправленной пользователем программе, которую я запускаю с помощью функционала класса Process, вносить изменения в реестр, запретить доступ к интернету, а также запретить чтение / запись файлов, папок и т.д.

- AppDomains не использую т.к. требуется поддержка не ДотНетовских языков программирования
- Виртуальные машины (Virtual Box + его API) слишком снизит производительность
- Docker контейнеры не подходят из-за сложности работы с ними, а также из-за потери в производительности
- Функционал Sandboxie слишком ограничен, и к тому же, он платный...
- Запуск на отдельном бесправном пользователе уже используется, но не помогает запретить запуск процессов пользовательской программе...

На этом скромном списке мои идеи исчерпались. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать в этой ситуации.

P.S. Подсистема тестирования работает на Windows, написана на C#.

Comment: Сами себе придумали проблемы и хотите их героически решить. Покажите мне, кто вам напел про посадку быстродействия в докере.

Comment: Допустим, среднестатистический школьный сервер: 2 ГБ ОЗУ, 4х ядерный ксеон эконом класса. Необходимо одновременно обслуживать до 15 человек. Из этого и вытекает проблема. И учителям информатики не объяснишь же (в некотором их числе), почему проверка решений происходит так долго...

Comment: @Sirkadirov: Запуск других процессов можно запретить юзеру при помощи административных шаблонов, по идее.

Comment: @Sirkadirov: Например: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/create-an-application-whitelist-policy-in-windows/ или https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-use-local-group-policy-whitelist-certain-programs-in-windows-7 (ищите по ключевым словам group policy).

Comment: @VladD: Знаю, такой вариант не подходит из-за того, что система предполагает установку на сервера школ, а данный метод слишком усложняет процесс... Но всё равно благодарю вас за информацию!

Comment: @Sirkadirov: Административные шаблоны по идее можно деплоить по сети администраторам, так что особых проблем быть не должно. Тем более, запрет-то только для ограниченного юзера.

Comment: @VladD: Над реализацией подумаю... Сегодня ещё реализовал поддержку Линукса, хотелось бы найти совместное решение. Ну во всяком случае спасибо, скорее всего сделаю так.